# change text color of title elements for a scene

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm creating a small Android mobile app using React Native and react-native-router-flux.

I've customized everything except the `leftTitle` and `rightTitle` property of my main screen.  I can name them, but I can't style them.  They remain this blue color as seen in the image below.

[image]

Here is the code for that scene:

```
<Scene
  rightTitle="Add"
  onRight = { () => Actions.employeeCreate() }
  key="employeeList"
  component={EmployeeList}
  title="Employees"
  leftTitle="Log Out"
  onLeft={ () => logUserOut() }
  initial
/>
```

Does anyone know how to change the color of the title text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Find **`react-native-router-flux`** folder in **`node modules`**
2. Navigate into **`react-native-router-flux > src > NavBar.js`**
3. Edit color style **`barRightButtonText`** and **`barLeftButtonText`** in StyleSheet like this

For right button text :

```
 barRightButtonText: {
    color: 'rgb(0, 122, 255)',    //Your rgb color code here
    textAlign: 'right',
    fontSize: 17,
  },
```

For left button text

```
 barLeftButtonText: {
    color: 'rgb(0, 122, 255)',  //Your rgb color code here
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontSize: 17,
  },
```

Comment: oh wow you have to edit it deep like that?  There's no way to pass it down as props?  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell  No there is nothing to do with props. Each and every library you need to edit the library src files in order to do such things

Comment: I was looking how to modify this for hours - thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As oppose to what @Akila Devinda said that props has nohting to do with the stylings. Yes you can style the navbar using props as indicated in the documentation of react-native-router-flux

[Click here for the documentation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md) as you can see I styled it myself by using props

[image: Sample]

Here is the code

```
const App = () => {
 return(
   <Router navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#3F51B5' }}>
    <Scene key="root">
    <Scene key="home" component={ HomeScreen } title="Home"  titleStyle={ { color: 
      "#ffffff" } } initial />
    <Scene key="about" component={ AboutScreen } title="About" titleStyle={ { color: 
         "#ffffff" } } navBarButtonColor="white"/>
   </Scene>
   </Router>
 )
}
```

In my opinion doing this way instead of styling directly in the src file would be better when defining a navbar specific style